What are conformal Killing spinors?
There are various definitions of Killing spinors and Conformal killing spinors that I see in literature which is a bit confusing to me. So, I want to clarify the nomenclature.
My question is for a generic manifold ($R \neq 0$), what is the definition of Conformal Killing Spinors and Killing Spinors? I've seen two different definitions of Killing Spinors: One says $\nabla_{\mu} \varepsilon = 0$, the other states $\nabla_{\mu} \varepsilon = \frac{\kappa}{2} \gamma_{\mu}\varepsilon$. Is the second one for Conformal Spinors? What is $\kappa$ for a generic spacetime? (Here $\nabla_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + \frac{1}{4}\omega_{\mu}^{ab}\sigma_{ab}$ is the Spin covariant derivative.)
I know that Killing spinors are "square root" of Killing vectors in the sense that their bilinears are the Killing vectors of the geometry. Does that same relation also hold for Conformal killing spinors and Conformal Killing vectors?

Have you looked at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Killing+spinor?

Yes, but the definitions and the relations with conformal killing vectors are still not clear to me unfortunately.
